# How to set TTL for future date records in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

How to set TTL for a record in Cassandra for future dates?

I need to set TTL for a date in future which would be active only for said number of seconds. E.g: I insert a record into cassandra table which would be active 5 days from now for 30 mins.

Answer (score 0):

TTLs can be specified by default (at the table level if not specified by the DML - e.g. INSERT) or at the DML level (e.g. you can specify TTL with each INSERT, UPDATE). Either approach will determine when the record expires. If you h ave something that you insert now that has a TTL of 5 days and 30  minutes, then specify that TTL value upon INSERT. The syntax would be:

```
INSERT INTO .... VALUES (...) USING TTL XXXXX.
```

Hopefully that helps??

-Jim